# Problem With Password Field

Tags: password, browser

I'm new to ubuntu and have just installed ubuntu 18.04 and I'm running Firefox which came bundled in the package.

I have a problem were I can't enter a password into the password field on certain websites, example: [www.middlemangone.com](https://www.middlemangone.com)

I've spent an hour searching for solutions, but I'm a bit hesitant to try some of the suggestions I found. One involved installing a deb file from GitHub and Bugzilla, while another suggested installing a snap version of Firefox.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Warning: Ubuntu 18.04 is *five years old*. We will stop answering questions about it forever in nine days. Consider installing a much newer release of Ubuntu, as this is unlikely to be your only question.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.  **FYI: The 18.04 tells you it was the 2018-April release (*year.month* format with 2000 taken from the year).. add 5 years to for EOSS (2023-April)**

Comment: Online tools like https://packages.ubuntu.com/ no longer provide details for anything older than 20.04 as the five years of support for *bionic* or 18.04 ended last month, so our ability to help is even more limited now. We'd need to have a *bionic* system around (to do enquiries at terminal) or have *devscripts* installed that allow searching of ESM releases such as 18.04 (*18.04 ESM official start date is 31-May-2023 so you're on-topic on this site until then*).  **I'd suggest installing a release with more than days/hours of supported life left**